# How to remove a duplicate tokens from a row dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have this dataframe containing tokens for sentiment analysis.

| stemmed |
| --- |
| ['min', 'tol', 'cilegon', 'serang', 'minim', 'lampu', 'terang', 'jalan', 'bayar', 'tol', 'mahal', 'emang', 'bayar', 'tol', 'doang', 'tah', 'tidak', 'plus', 'terang', 'jalan', 'tidak', 'lubang'] |
| ['moga', 'selesai', 'guna', 'jalan', 'tol', 'nyaman', 'lancar', 'jalan'] |

I want to remove the duplicate token, for example "jalan" and "tol". So the new dataframe should be like this:

| stemmed |
| --- |
| ['min', 'tol', 'cilegon', 'serang', 'minim', 'lampu', 'terang', 'jalan', 'bayar', 'mahal', 'emang', 'doang', 'tah', 'tidak', 'plus', 'lubang'] |
| ['moga', 'selesai', 'guna', 'jalan', 'tol', 'nyaman', 'lancar', 'jalan'] |

Comment: Why are there 2 `'jalan'`s in the second row of the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *listcomp* with a helper func to keep unique tokens while preserving their order :

```
# if needed
# from ast import literal_eval
# df["stemmed"] = df["stemmed"].apply(literal_eval)

def dropdup(row):
    seen = set()
    unique_tokens = []
    for t in row:
        if t not in seen:
            unique_tokens.append(t)
            seen.add(t)
    return unique_tokens

df["stemmed"] = [dropdup(row) for row in df["stemmed"]]
```

Output :

|  | stemmed |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | ['min', 'tol', 'cilegon', 'serang', 'minim', 'lampu', 'terang', 'jalan', 'bayar', 'mahal', 'emang', 'doang', 'tah', 'tidak', 'plus', 'lubang'] |
| 1 | ['moga', 'selesai', 'guna', 'jalan', 'tol', 'nyaman', 'lancar'] |